# How do you place EXIF tags into a JPG, having the raw jpeg buffer in C++?

Tags: c++, jpeg, exif

I am having a bit of a problem.

I get a RAW char* buffer from a camera and I need to add this tags before I can save it to disk. Writing the file to disk and reading it back again is not an option, as this will happen thousands of times.

The buffer data I receive from the camera does not contain any EXIF information, apart from the Width, Height and Pixels per Inch.

Any ideas? (C++)

Comment: ➝ look at the XMP Metadata Toolkit (Adobe, but somewhat opensource), in particular XMPFiles...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at this [PDF](http://www.exif.org/Exif2-1.PDF), on page 20 you have a diagram showing you were to place or modify your exif information. What is the difference with a file on disk ?

Does the JPEG buffer of your camera contain an EXIF section already ?

Comment: No the JPEG buffer from the camera does not contain the EXIF section

Comment: Thanks. This helps...it differs from the JFIF standard

Answer (score 1):

What's the difference? Why would doing it to a file on the disk be any different from doing it in memory?

Just do whatever it is you do after you read the file from the disk..

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know EXIF data in JPEG is continuous subpart of file.
So

1. prepare EXIF data in memory
2. write part of JPEG file upto EXIF
3. write prepared EXIF
4. write rest of JPEG file

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look into [Exiv2](http://www.exiv2.org/) library. I know it can work on files but I suppose it also has functions to work on memory buffers.

Comment: Note that Exiv2 is not free for commercial use.

Comment: That is a terrible misunderstanding actually. Exiv2 is dual licensed GPL and commercial. GPL has its requirements - yes - but doesn't forbid you to use it in commercial products.

Comment: Sorry about this. So is it OK to use Exiv2 as part of a commercial product if I do not modify Exiv2 source files (but include its header files from my source files and link to its source files)?

Comment: Your commercial product must then be open source and GPL licensed. That's the limitation. But no one actually forbids you to monetize it. Hence my comment about misunderstanding.

Otherwise you can buy a commercial license.

Comment: So it's not free. You pay by making your product an open-source under a specific license.
I still think that the claim that Exiv2 is free for commercial products, is misleading (because it's not free for most commercial products).